# How can I scan participants' QR tickets to enter an event?

Tags: applications, qr-code, barcode

I am hosting an event where I would like to have all participants receive a secret key in the form of a SHA-hashed secret, converted to a QR code. This would represent their ticket to enter the event. I would then like to be able to use a large list of these secrets to verify the participant's ticket (QR code) and automatically mark that participant as present, to make sure no tickets are used multiple times.

Is there a way to use QR codes to verify if a certain value is in my list of keys, and then check off that particular key? Or is there another way I could use such a QR-based ticket system to verify a participant's ticket? Would I somehow need to write my own app to do that, or are there already existing systems I could use for this?

If I am posting this in the wrong place, please let me know where I should post it instead. I couldn't think of any better place than here.

Comment: QR codes just hold strings (or numbers or binary). How you distribute a unique id to your guests and how you check them are off-topic here as your QR codes can be on paper. As to how to read them, you can build a web site which uses a USB camera to scan and match those against your database (also off-topic). Such a website (if built properly & asking for camera permission) can be accessed via a mobile browser.

Comment: You should take a look onto Apple's Wallet system which can also be used for digital tickets. Even so Apple of course does not support Android such tickets can be issues and used for Android users.